# PHP Dynamic Prepared Statement - Number of Elements Not Matching

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, prepared-statement

I am trying to construct a prepared statement dynamically and I keep getting the following error:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string 
doesn't match number of bind variables in
```

When I echo my statements the number of type definitions matches the bind variable so I don't know what is wrong. I think my code may be passing in strings, quotes or something instead of variables but I'm new to prepared statement and not sure how to check my query. When using simple `mysqli_query` I can echo the query and see were my error is at. I'm not sure how to do this with prepared statements so I'm hoping someone can help me with uncovering my error.

I am trying to construct the prepares statement dynamically so that I can reuse the code as follows:

```
$db = mysqli_stmt_init($dbconnection);

//i have looped through my fields and constructed a string that when echoed returns this: ?, ?, ?, ?, I use sub str just to remove the last comma and space leaving me with the string ?, ?, ?, ?. Ive echoed this to the browser to make sure it is correct.

$preparedQs = substr($preparedQs, 0, -2);

 //I then loop through each field using their datatype and constructs the type string as follows ssss. Ive echoed this to the browser to make sure it is correct.

$preparedType = 'ssss';

 //I then loop through my post array verifying and cleaning the data and then it constructing a string of clean values that results in Mike, null, Smith, Sr., (First, Middle, Last, Suffix) I use substr again just to remove the last comma and space. Ive echoed this to the browser to make sure it is correct.

    $cleanstr = substr($cleanstr, 0, -2);

 //I then explode that string into a an array that I can loop through and assign/bind each value to a variable as follows and use substr again to remove last comma and space.

    $cleanstr = explode(", ", $cleanstr);
    $ct2 = 0;
    foreach ( $cleanstr as $cl){
        $name = "a".$ct2;
        $$name = $cl;
        $varstr .= "$".$name.", ";
        $ct2 = $ct2 +1;    
    }
   $varstr = substr($varstr, 0, -2);

 //ive echoed the $varstr to the browser and get $a1, $a2, $a3, $a4. I have also echo their value outside of the loop and know values have been assigned.

 //I then try to assign each step above the appropriate prepared statement place holder

   $stmt = mysqli_stmt_prepare($db, "INSERT INTO Contacts VALUES (". $preparedQs. ")");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($db, "'".$preparedType."'", $varstr);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

I'm am not sure what I am doing wrong because when I echo `$preparedQs`, `$preparedType` and `$varstr` they all have the same number of elements yet I'm getting the "mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in.." error. All i can think is that I have quotes or something where I shouldn't but I've tried adding and removing quotes in certain areas and cant get the error to resolve.

Also, I read some posts about passing null in prepared statement but even when I replace the null with an actual value, I still get the same error.

It's probably worth noting that when using simple procedural `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_real_escape_string` to clean my data things work fine. I am trying to improve my security by converting my application to prepared statement simply for the added security.

// EDIT / DIFFERENT

This question is different for two reason

1. I am using procedural coding and not object or PDO. So being new to prepared statements, the examples given aren't helpful even after trying to make sense of them.
2. I am using an insert statement, not a select or update statement which in procedural php the query string is writen differently for insert than for select or update statements.

Will someone help me with the procedural insert solution to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: You're passing `$varstr` as a string, not the actual individual variables it's expecting.

Comment: So should this be an array? How would I convert this string to individual variables? Thank you.

Comment: Please see edits above.

Comment: @aynber & Shadow please see edits and reopen my question. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference what kind of statement it is. The building of the execution line is the same.

Comment: Again being new im trying my best to follow. It would be greatly helpful if you put that into a post using my example above. Thank you.